# Mysql query to get lowest value from multiple conditions using UNION operator

Tags: mysql

I have price table with three columns:

```
id, price, product_id.
```

`product_id` can contain multiple prices.

I need to get lowest price product_id when query perform in mysql.

I am using multiple conditions using UNION operator in this table data is coming but results are wrong.

In this table product_id 101 has 4999 but I am getting 5000, even I have set order by price ASC

Here is my mysql fiddle link
[mysql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/15)

Comment: Learn how to use the MIN() function and group by. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/21/0

Comment: Given your sample data in the fiddle, could you show the expected output?  Something like this maybe? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/55/0

Comment: Hi, I have solved this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/56

Comment: ok.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/55/0 gives the same results and doesn't use a union.  The issue was with not understanding the need for grouping.     To answer the question asked below: "How should you get both price ranges with out using union or JOINS can you explain this ?" by using a case statement to define ranges in the select and group by it.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't check this, this is good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic SQL.

```
select product_id, min(price) as price
from price
group by product_id;
```

To fetch minimum prices per product for a given range add them to case statement in group by clause:

```
select product_id, min(price) as price
from price
group by product_id, case when price between 100 and 5000 then 1 else 2 end;
```

[**SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609425/1)

Comment: try mysql fiddle link of above exact

Comment: I said exact link of above my fiddle where is unions in your example ?

Comment: You dont need union. Why would you even do that? Check the output... Also, when you aren't grouping by every field that is in the select statement and isn't aggregated MySQL will provide RANDOM results.

Comment: why you are not understanding my question here, I need to fetch low prices from given range of prices. ex: if user need 100-5000 and 5001-1000 prices of products how should you get both price ranges with out using union or JOINS can you explain this ?

Comment: I can get low price using MIN() this is general I know that. explain this query using my schema if you are capable. SELECT id,price,product_id FROM price pr WHERE price >= 100 AND price <= 5000 group by product_id UNION SELECT id,price,product_id FROM price pr WHERE price >= 5001 AND price <= 10000 group by product_id order by price ASC

Comment: The thing is my query __matches__ your expected output. I've edited my answer to show you what you __probably__ want, but are not capable of describing.

Comment: I have given full schema and query in fiddle, without understanding my expectation using my query you have given another query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122116/discussion-between-jack-brone-and-kamil-g).

Comment: I'm sorry, your output is basically like mine. I'm not able to help you any further since you keep insisting on some UNION which not only me finds unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the ID of each record with the min price.

```
Select p.* from price p
INNER JOIN  (Select product_ID, Min(Price) as price from `price` group by Product_ID) sub
 on sub.product_Id = p.product_Id
 and sub.price = p.price
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/21/0)

Otherwise...

```
Select product_ID, Min(Price) as price from `price` group by Product_ID
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/24/0)

---- UPDATE----

Still not sure I understand the question... which is why I asked for expected output given your data.  I may be able to infer the requirements which i'm not getting.  As it stands I had NO idea why a union was needed, nor how this "grouping" came into play.

```
SELECT p.* from price p
INNER JOIN  (Select product_ID, Min(Price) as price from `price` group by Product_ID) sub
 on sub.product_Id = p.product_Id
 and sub.price = p.price
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca76/55/0)

Assuming no overlap of product_ID in ranges...

Comment: here I need to get prices by given price ranges not with ID's. Price Ranges can be multiple.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT pr.id,MIN(pr.price),pr.product_id FROM price pr WHERE pr.price >= 100 AND pr.price <= 5000 group by pr.product_id UNION SELECT pr.id,MIN(pr.price),pr.product_id FROM price pr WHERE pr.price >= 5001 AND pr.price <= 10000 group by pr.product_id